# Thailand administrative boundaries and population dataset

Tags: population

Does anyone know where I can get polygons for Thailand admin 3 level (tambon) with population data?

Comment: Obvious question: have you looked at openstreetmaps.org for the polygons and geonames.org for the population data?

Comment: @nrsbrn, also, possibly https://data.humdata.org/group/tha or http://www.diva-gis.org/. I red somewhere on http://tambon.blogspot.ru/ that population data by tambon is not officially published.